# NPM script to automate package increment and GIT push

Tags: git, npm

I am trying to do the following within one script(or excecute via one command)

1. Run rollup
2. Add the files that have changed/created/discarded
3. Increment the package version number (patch)
4. Git Commit and add the package version number
5. Push git

Essentially i want to automate the push process.

Here is the script i created but the git message is "MSG" instead of the version

```
"npm run rollup && git add . && npm version patch -git-tag-version false && SET MSG=npm version utilities --version git commit -q -m  MSG && git push"
```

The following command works except the MSG variable does not contain the actual version which is calculated by `SET MSG=npm version utilities --version`

I attempted it with an ampersand between setting the `MSG` variable and git commit

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be too difficult to write in one CMD line due to lack of backtick support. Instead consider using [ShellJS](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) or [Tasksfile](https://github.com/pawelgalazka/tasksfile) and having your script run that instead:

```
"npx task package"
```

```
// tasksfile.js
const { sh, cli } = require('tasksfile')

function package() {
    sh('rollup');
    sh('git add .');
    sh('npm version patch -git-tag-version false');

    const version = sh('npm version utilities --version');

    sh(`git commit -q -m ${version}`);
    sh('git push');
}

cli({
  package
})
```